# Paradigms fit for UI programming

Tags: object-oriented, paradigms

This is a more specific question (or actually two, but they are related) coming from the comments of [OOP technology death](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87972/oop-technology-death) where someone stated that OOP is not the right paradigm for GUI programming.

Reading the comments there and here I still have the feeling there are things to learn: which programming paradigms are considered good fits and why are they better than others (perhaps with examples to illustrate?)

*I removed the tk-example from the title and question*

Comment: @Inca - keep in mind, that SK-logic (who originated this comment) fights OOP on every possible occasion - like if he had a fanatic mission. I strongly doubt that he can really prove that tk is not related to OOP at all.

Comment: -1: for quoting a personal opinion as if it were fact.  "OOP is not the right paradigm for GUI programming" would fly in the face of C# and Objective C which seem to depend very heavily on OOP for GUI programming.  If it's not the right paradigm then all of Apple's huge market share doesn't really exist or something.

Comment: @S.Lott it's not the right paradigm though, GUI should be declarative. You seem to be confusing popularity with what is right.

Comment: @Raynos: "declarative".  As in, some related objects?  I don't get how declarative is not a bunch of relationships among a bunch of objects.   And.  That's seems off-topic for this question.  The question seems to be about OO, not better ways to write GUI's.  The title seems to be misleading compared with the actual question.  Neither are very good.

Comment: @S.Lott: how should I adapt 'where it was stated' to more reflect that it is an opinion than it already does? And how do you think I should otherwise improve the question or title?

Comment: @Inca I think the answer is that Tk is probably OOP. Also the question should either be "Why is OO bad for GUI dev." or "Is Tk not OO?" @S.Lott the question is "Why is OO not a good fit for UI" and the answer is because declarative is a better fit, or otherwise rephrased please stop using the OO as a silver bullet for everything.

Comment: @Inca: Consider disregarding it entirely as mere hyperbole.

Comment: @Andreas_D: thanks for pointing that out. I would still be interested in explanations either way, because I want to know where this comes from.

Comment: @S.Lott, shall you really call HTML and WPF "object-oriented" languages? Are there any objects which interact by passing messages to each other?

Comment: @Andreas_D, it's not fair. I'm not fighting OOP per se - I'm in fact a heavy user of it, as I did a lot of agent-based simulations stuff (which is entirely OO). I'm only against a misuse of a single, narrow, trivial metalinguistic abstraction when there is an infinite number of better abstractions is available.

Comment: @SK-logic - sorry, in fact I can't know, you're right. - my rating was based on some of your comments against OOP (per se - that how *I* understood them)

Comment: @SK-logic: "shall you really call HTML and WPF "object-oriented" languages?" I have no idea how to respond to this.  I can't recall ever posting it, so there's no way to respond.  Is there a context in which I posted something like this?  Can you provide a link or a reference?

Comment: @S.Lott, I'm answering to "*I don't get how declarative is not a bunch of relationships among a bunch of objects*".

Comment: @SK-logic: Sorry.  I can't follow the logic at all.

Comment: @S.Lott, if a declarative language is always "a bunch of relationships among a bunch of objects", then a declarative language HTML is a "bunch of relationships among a bunch of objects", which in turn is supposed to mean that it is object-oriented. Otherwise I've got no idea what you've been trying to say with that sentence.

Comment: @SK-logic: HTML is not an object oriented programming language.  HTML, like many languages, declares relationships among objects.  Indeed, HTML can be represented in Python (or other OO) language as a bunch of static object declarations.  However, HTML is not an OO language; it can be represented by an OO language, since it's just objects.

Comment: @S.Lott, how does it "declare relationships among objects"? There are no objects in an OO sense.

Comment: @SK-logic: "There are no objects in an OO sense".  You're right.  I don't understand the distinction between objects and "objects in an OO sense".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not normally a proponent of OOP, but I would say that GUI programming presents some of the best opportunities to use the strong points of OOP. Implementing various widgets is made a lot easier by using OOP's polymorphism and inheritance. [PLT Racket's GUI library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html#%28part._.Core_.Windowing_.Classes%29) is a good example.

Comment: Functional reactive programming yet seems to be a better fit.

Comment: @SK-logic: You could make a very good case for that, and some interesting work in Common Lisp (have you heard of Cells?) has been done in that direction. I'll edit my answer to make it more precise.

Answer (score 6):

A typical GUI, made of widgets and their layout, is entirely declarative. Widgets per se would not interact with each other, so a notion of objects and messages is somewhat alien here. Hierarchial declarative DSLs are a sort of a mainstream currently, with Tk being one of the early examples, and WPF as a more modern approach to the same thing. Functional reactive programming is another interesting (but not very widespread) approach.

Some people tend to see OOP anywhere where a hierarchy is defined, which is wrong - there is absolutely no connection between strict hierarchies (read - algebraic data types) and Kay's definition of OOP.

Comment: In my experience, widgets do need to interact with each other to make a better GUI, and the more declarative systems I have encountered (certain xml-based ones, including HTML+css) certainly lack possibilities in the interaction-part. Also, my experiences with incorporating UI using declarative (prolog) and functional (Haskell) did not really give the impression it was easy. Do you have sources I could look at that specifically discuss more of this? I have only come up with very abstract (or very basic) examples that don't explain much as to why certain approaches work better